# How to get geom_bar to respect bar widths when only one factor level and NA are present?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating bar plots using geom_bar and I am using scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) to keep factor levels on the x-axis that are not present in the data (I am creating similar plots with different data for comparison and want to keep everything consistent).

When there is only one factor level in the data along with NA, the bar widths get much wider (as if drop=FALSE isn't being respected). With more than one factor level, or without NA present it works as expected. I do want to have NA as a bar (when there is NA).

Below are four examples that I used to try to figure out where the issue was. #1-3 work as expected. I was expecting the bars in #4 to have the same width as in #3.  Any help appreciated.

```
# 1
# without NA, multiple levels present,  expected results
mwe <- data.frame(x = c(seq(1,20,each=5)))
mwe$cat <- cut(mwe$x, breaks = c(0, 3,7,19, 200, 400), include.lowest = TRUE)
ggplot(mwe, aes(cat)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)

# 2
# without NA, one level present,  expected results
mwe <- data.frame(x = rep(10,100))
mwe$cat <- cut(mwe$x, breaks = c(0, 3,7,19, 200, 400), include.lowest = TRUE)
ggplot(mwe, aes(cat)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)

# 3
# with NA, multiple levels present,  expected results
mwe <- data.frame(x = c(seq(1,20,each=5)))
mwe[c(5,10,50), "x"] = NA
mwe$cat <- cut(mwe$x, breaks = c(0, 3,7,19, 200, 400), include.lowest = TRUE)
ggplot(mwe, aes(cat)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)

# 4
# with NA, only one level present, NOT expected results
mwe <- data.frame(x = rep(10,100))
mwe[c(5,10,50), "x"] = NA
mwe$cat <- cut(mwe$x, breaks = c(0, 3,7,19, 200, 400), include.lowest = TRUE)
ggplot(mwe, aes(cat)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

Comment: This is a bug which was already reported on [GH](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5639) and which should be fixed in `ggplot2 3.5.0`, i.e. I can reproduce in `ggplot2 3.4.4` but it works fine in `ggplot2 3.5.0`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQauE.png

Comment: Thanks! It also worked for me with ggplot2 3.5.0.